# Debugging crashes vshost.exe on oledbconnection.open, works fine without vshost

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am running a simple test app that opens an OLEDB connection, retrieves a single value, then closes.  The compiled (console) app works fine, but running it from the IDE causes either a silent close (if it's a winforms app) or a crash of vshost32.exe if it's a console app.

The devenv is `VB 2010 Express` on Windows x64, but I have the configuration manager on the solution set to "Debug" - "x86".[image]

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim server As String = "xxxxx"
        Dim username As String = "xxxxx"
        Dim password As String = "xxxxx"
        Dim schema As String = "xxxxx"

        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format( _
            "Provider=SLXOLEDB.1;Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={3};User ID={1};Password={2};Extended Properties=LOG=ON;Connect Timeout=5;", _
            server, username, password, schema)

        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()

        Dim query As String = "SELECT USERID FROM USERSECURITY WHERE USERCODE=?"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("usercode", username)
        Dim userid As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString

        Console.WriteLine("UserID is {0}", userid)

        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        con.Close()
        con = Nothing

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Why are you using `?` and not `@Usercode` combined with `AddWithValue("@usercode, username)`? Also. You should declare and use the connection with a `using` not to hog resources on the sql server.

Comment: Not for your crash but for the code you pasted it is. Thats why i made it a comment not an answer. If you run it with a debugger and step each line what happens.

Comment: I step to the line with con.Open(), and when I execute that statement, it hangs for a couple of seconds, then crashes the vshost.  Regarding the `?`, to be honest I can't remember.  I think it was something to do with the OLEDB provider I'm using not liking them, but I may be miss-remembering that :D  I'll test it once I get it working again!  I can't totally use the "it's legacy code" excuse, as it's all my code, but some if it is quite old and written when I was EVEN MORE ignorant than I am now.

Comment: If the problem is at the Open it has to be the connection string or the provider. I've seen the vshost crashing when there were unmanaged exceptions on the provider (SLXOLEDB.1)

Comment: Damn.  I changed my test to use a standard SQL provider (I need the SalesLogix provider) and it works.  So I guess it's an SLXOLEDB provider problem meaning I may struggle to get a solution.  It was working on my previous x64 PC though, so maybe I can juggle some DLL's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple.

The SalesLogix OLEDB provider works fine, but you can only debug if the IDE is launched with Administrator permissions.

Some digging around with procmon would probably tell which keys/files are being accessed, but in our case I can just debug with an elevated IDE.

Comment: It is politically correct to mark your own answer as correct on stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah, I just like to give it a day in case someone comes up with something insightful :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable vshost to see what happens.

I also would look at the Output window, maybe you have some valuable information there.

Comment: If I disable the vshost, then the error changes to "oledbtest.exe stopped responding" - but still nothing in the output window.  If I choose "debug" from the two options, I just get returned to the IDE.  In no case are any exceptions thrown in the IDE.